# Splitting line buffers into two separate polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, buffer, polygon-creation

In QGIS, I have a layer of numerous vector lines that need to be buffered. Once they've been buffered, I'd like to have those polygons split into two, with the original line being the segment that splits them. This also needs to be done with a vector layer that has roughly 10,000 lines in it, so I won't be able to complete this line by line.

The first picture simply shows what the layer of lines looks like. The second picture shows how I'd like to be able to identify specific parts of the buffers after they've been buffered.

[image: Lines prior to getting buffered.]

[image: Lines get buffered, then those buffers need to be split.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Algorithms(tools):

- Use the ["Single Sided Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#single-sided-buffer) twice for left and right side
- Merge two results using the ["Merge Vector Layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers)

Tool options:

[image]

Two results:
[image]

Merged:

[image]

Comment: Where do I find the Single Sided Buffer tool? Using QGIS 3.12

Comment: It's in the Vector Geometry group in 3.28.  Type buffer in your processing search box to see if it comes up.

Comment: It should be in Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T) > Vector Geometry.